# Knime automatic Workflow with a Database

Tags: oracle, automation, powerbi, knime

I want to create multiple Workflows in Knime with a Oracle Database so that i have one big Database in the end with the customized tables i need. The final Knime Data i want to upload to PowerBI to create a kind of Reporting.

**Is it possible to automize the Workflow at a certain time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - there are two approaches:

1. KNIME server (cloud or on premise), which is a paid license.  It allows you to schedule workflows to run at set times or intervals
2. Via batch command - see https://www.knime.com/faq#q12 for the details.  If you go this way, it is easiest to set up a `.bat` or `.sh` file (depending on whether you are on Windows or Linux) to run the workflow, and then schedule it using either `crontab -e` on Linux of the Windows Task Scheduler